# Do some spark or spark.sql operations do collect in intermediate processing?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have faced some out of memory issues in spark and most solutions tell me to reduce the collect() operations or check broadcast tables.

So I have a simple question, why does this happen when I am not using collect or broadcast tables in my code?

Dose spark perform collect in the intermediate processing for some operations?

Comment: Maybe the cluster just needs more resources (memory, compute power)? Even without an explicit call to collect, some intermediate processing will need to happen and some data may need to be transferred from one node to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does, I don't have an exhaustive list but if you call `.toPandas()` on a Spark DF for instance, it will collect the data on the driver.

Even though you're not directly calling the `collect`.

Comment: can we some how check if our code is doing collect some where?

Comment: @Andy_101, I don't know if there's a way to know beforehand, except knowing what the functions or methods you are calling do. After execution I guess you should be able to see if there was a collect by inspecting the Physical Plan.